# Polymer DOM update after viewport refresh

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

I've been trying to work this out but sofar have been unable to find an answer. My Polymer element loads a base template JSON file, which is then run through a `dom-repeat` to create a basic HTML page.
Then another JSON text-file is loaded, which completes the various areas of the HTML with a JS function.
Upon button-click form child, a function is run that triggers the loading of another JSON file that adds additional info. This all works fine.
But when I go out of the page and back in it, it has remembered all my settings but does not display things correctly. It displays the `translatedText` well and the html code is there, but it does not complete the html code for the `originalText`.

It seems to want to load the last JSON file before the DOM is properly rendered. So I want it to refresh the whole DOM, but how do I do this?

My MWE:

```
<template>
<iron-ajax
      auto
      url="basetext.json"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{baseText}}"></iron-ajax>

  <div class="textcontent">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{baseText.lines}}" as="line">
        <div class="lineblock">
            <div class="line" id="line{{line.lineid}}" inner-h-t-m-l="{{line.linetext}}"></div>
              <template is="dom-if" if="[[extraShowEnabled]]">
                      <div class="linepi" id='linepi{{line.lineid}}' inner-h-t-m-l="{{line.linetext}}"></div>
              </template>
        </div>
      </template>
  </div>

  <template is="dom-if" if="[[extraLoadEnabled]]">
      <iron-ajax
              auto
              url="originaltext.json"
              handle-as="json"
              last-response="{{originalText}}"></iron-ajax>
  </template>

<iron-ajax
      auto
      url="translatedtext.json"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{translatedText}}"></iron-ajax>
</template>


<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'text-page',

      properties: {
        translatedText: Object,
        originalText: Object,
        extraShowEnabled: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        },
        extraLoadEnabled: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        },
        showViewer: {
          type: String,
          value: "none"
        }
      },
      observers: [
       'setView(showViewer)',
       ' _computeSegments(translatedText,".line")',
       ' _computeSegments(originalText,".linepi")'
      ],
      ready: function() {
        this.addEventListener('eventFromChild', this.changeView);
      },
      changeView: function(event) {
        this.showViewer = event.detail.selectedView;
      },
      setView: function(showViewer) {
        \\ first some code here to reset all css.

        if (showViewer === "none") {
          this.extraShowEnabled = false;
          this.extraLoadEnabled = false;
        }
        if (showViewer === "sidebyside") {
          this.extraShowEnabled = true;
          this.extraLoadEnabled = true;
          this._computeSegments(this.originalText,".linepi");
          this._addSideBySideCode();
        }
      },
      _computeSegments: function(inputText,linetype) {
        if (inputText) {
          Array.from(this.querySelectorAll(linetype+" sc-segment")).forEach(item => item.innerHTML = inputText.segments[item.id]);
        }
      },
      _addSideBySideCode: function() {
        \\ this function just adds some css.
        },
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should try to use a compute function result as a dom-repeat item source, something like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itmesByParamsCompute(baseText, originalText, translatedText, extraloadEnabled, ...)}}" as="line">
```

Add as many params as You need to recompute on. Then that compute function should return a valid source anytime at least one of the paras changes.

Also keep in mind, that if any of these params will become undefined that compute function might be **ignored completely**. Work around for this is making this opposite way - one property which is modified from manny observers, something like this:

```
properties: {
   items_to_use: {
      type: Array,
      value: []
   },
   translatedText: {
      type: Object,
      observer: 'updateItemsToUse'
   },
   originalText: {
      type: Object,
      observer: 'updateItemsToUse'
   }
},
updateItemsToUse: function (data) {
    let updatedArray = this.someMixFixFunction(this.item_to_use, data);
    this.set('items_to_use', updatedArray);
},
someMixFixFunction: function (old_array, data_to_apply) {
   // do some merging or what ever You need here, for example
   let updatedArray = old_array.concat(data_to_apply);

   return updatedArray;
}
```